# jQuery UI sortable is making my element "absolute" on the 2nd drag

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, zurb-foundation, jquery-ui-sortable, zurb-foundation-6

The first time I drag an element in this sortable list, it works great. The second time, it positions absolute and flies over to the left.

As you can see in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/scotnery/d3pamtgo/7/

```
x.sortable({
    axis: 'y',
    handle: '.handle',
    placeholder: 'sortable-placeholder',
    opacity: 0.5,
    sort: function(event, ui){
        $(this).find('.numeral').each(function() {
            $(this).html("#");
        });
        // the handel item that was dragged
        handle = ui.item.find(".handle")
        handle.removeClass("fi-list").addClass("fi-shopping-bag");

        ui.item.addClass("freshest");
        $(".sortable-placeholder").height(ui.item.outerHeight());
    },
    stop: function(event,ui){
        ui.item.removeClass("freshest",{duration:1000});
        handle = ui.item.find(".handle");
        handle.removeClass("fi-shopping-bag").addClass("fi-list");
        // renumber each row in the html
        i = 1;
        $(this).find('.numeral').each(function() {
            $(this).html(i);
            i++;
        });
    },
    update: function (event, ui) {
        updateSort(this);
    }
}).disableSelection();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sortable works better with **static** positioning, lists or tables for example. When you specify a different positioning, then jQuery tries to keep track of the position and assigns values to **left** and **top** when it's not needed. One simple solution in your case would be to avoid setting positioning on your booking-box elements. Change this line in your css:

```
.act-box, .ticket-box, .booking-box{ transition: background-color 1s ease;}
```

and it works: https://jsfiddle.net/03xqpkga/11/

If you need to set position, then you can use **beforeStop** event to remove the **left** that's being assigned:

```
 beforeStop: function(e, ui){
    ui.item[0].style.left = "";
 }
```